# Classify QR Code with AVFoundation - objective C

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, qr-code

I'm new with QR Code.
I use AVFoundation to detect QR Code and decode it to a text. 
I want to ask that: How can I know the text is a link or a contact or a number,...
I mean: With a QR code, can I know what type is it with using AVFoundation?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You may use UITextView. It will automatically detect link,number or URL

Comment: @Rahul Patel: Thank you for reply. I'm a new bie, could you please tell me more details.
Or could you give me some code? And if I want to detect if the qr code string is a map or contact, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the QR code, you can read the text by using a scanner seperately and if you need to read the text in xcode then you need to use this piece of code.

```
- (BOOL)startReading {
    NSError *error;

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    return YES;
}
```

> since this AVFoundation is used to capture motion picture we can capture the QR code and then we can read it. For further reference you can look in to 
>   [How To Scan QR Code Using AVFoundation Framework](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but maybe you misunderstood my mind.