# QR Code Classify after read

Tags: objective-c, qr-code

I use AVFoundation to read Qr code.
After, Get the Qr code String, How can I check if it is a link or a telephone number or a contact or a map or some thing else?

Comment: You want to take a look at `Regular Expression`

Comment: This likes like a repeat of a question asked less than a day ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270877/classify-qr-code-with-avfoundation-objective-c